# How to define macro of macros in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a macro of macros in C? Usually, the body of the macro-definition string contains, the operators of the language.

However sometimes there is a need to describe conditional macros in the body of macros, as it is does in macro-assembler. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you read what `#define` and `#ifdef` can do? If not, today's the day to start. Remember, you can do really crazy things with macros, nobody can stop you, but just because you can doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by conditional macros in the body of macros?  maybe give an example.  you can do #define x(a,b) a(b) where a is another macro.

Comment: Try it. What happened?

Comment: It is not possible to write a macro that defines other macros.    It is possible to write a macro that uses other macros, such as `#define X(x) Y(x)` where `Y` is a macro.   It is also also possible to conditionally define macros (e.g.  define a macro differently depending on whether another macro is defined or not).

Comment: Even if you embed a preprocessor directive (other than `_Pragma`) in the body of a macro definition, the macro expansion process will not recognize the text as a preprocessor directive.  So, you can't use `#define X #ifdef Y #define Z(x) … #else #define Z(x) … #endif` or anything similar, regardless of how you try to put newlines into the macro body.

Comment: Once you start trying to get clever with macros, you soon learn the limitations of Visual Studio's C preprocessor. :(

Comment: Don't get too complex with macros, they are an absolute pig to debug and future generations will not thank you.  KISS (Keep It Simple Sir)

Comment: Yes, this is not possible for standard C. Maybe it's right. Thank for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You can define a macro of a macro as in a macro containing another macro.

(2) However, you *cannot* define a macro of a macro like `#define INCLUDE #define STDH include <stdio.h>`.

Here, a very simple macro-based Hello World program is provided (for the first case). Here, `MAIN` is the macro containing a macro `HELLOWORLD`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HELLOWORLD printf("Hello, World!") // Macro
#define MAIN int main() { HELLOWORLD; return 0; } // Macro containing HELLOWORLD macro
MAIN
```

is preprocessed to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    HELLOWORLD;
    return 0;
}
```

which is then preprocessed to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is not possible for standard C. Maybe it's right. Thanks.

Comment: I believe processors also use different approach for macro. It would be insufficient use of resources to run predecessor 2 times.